# Created a dynamic string and want to fetch list size on the basis of that string

Tags: apex, list, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

I have an object that is having multiple child objects.
I want to perform certain actions only if the current record has child records associated with it.
For this I am checking the related list's size first, dynamically.But I am facing issues while saving my code :

```
for(Lead objLeadRec : lstLead) {
    for(LC_Setup_Map_Related_List__c objRelatedList1 : lstRelatedListRecords){
        relatedChildObjName = objRelatedList1.tdc_tlc__Child_Object__c.replace('__c','s__r');

        System.debug('relatedChildObjName'+relatedChildObjName);
        if(objLeadRec.relatedChildObjName.size() >0){
            hasRelatedListRecords = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing issue on this line, since the list name which I want to query, I have created using a string ,

```
if(objLeadRec.relatedChildObjName.size() >0){
```

Can anyone suggest any workaround. Can't hardcode object names as this code belongs to a managed package and the object names can be different in different orgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the size of the child related list, use following as `relatedChildObjName` is of `String` type

```
if(objLeadRec.getSobjects(relatedChildObjName) != null && objLeadRec.getSobjects(relatedChildObjName).size() >0)
```

Use Null check to **avoid** `Attempt to de-reference a null object error`

Refer [getSobjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Comment: it has displayed the following error :  Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void size() from the type Object at line 95 column 68

Answer (score 0):

Sobject.getSobjects('child relationship name') is the way to get child list
Please try the below code to dynamic fetch child related list and check size on it

```
if(objLeadRec.getSobjects(relatedChildObjName).size() >0)
```

For more reference please check the below URL
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm